# Angular library secondary entry points that depend on each other

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library, ng-packagr

I'm trying to make an angular library with secondary entry point for every module.

I have three modules: A, B and C.
A is standalone, but B depends on C, meaning I have `import` to get `C.module.ts` in `B.module.ts`.

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/the-best-way-to-architect-your-angular-libraries-87959301d3d3), so I have a `package.json`, `index.ts` and `public_api.ts` files in every module.

When I try to build the lib, I get the following error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point '@org/library-name/src/lib/A'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
Bundling to UMD
Minifying UMD bundle
Writing package metadata
Built @org/library-name/src/lib/A

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point '@org/library-name/src/lib/B'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: Unable to write a reference to CComponent in /.../projects/library-name/src/lib/C/C.component.ts from /.../projects/library-name/src/lib/C/C.module.ts
```

Any idea on how to make it work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure out any solution? I've the same issue..

Comment: Can you provide a repository with the codebase to take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you how I workarounded this problem.

The problem here is to understand how `ng-packagr` builds our libraries depending the entry-points/folder structure.

In my particular situation I had the following structure:

[image: folder_structure]

The output is 2 chunks, right? `my-lib/common` and `my-lib/common/big-chunk`

It happens that the secondary entry points are built BEFORE the main one, so having a shared logic, I will need to put it (and export it) on the secondary entry-point `my-lib/common/big-chunk` and use it on the main one `my-lib/common`.

If you find yourself with the need of sharing logic, consider to create a `shared` entry point.

I found very tricky to use and implement secondary entry points and some refactors might be needed to make them work and take the whole benefit they can bring, but overall I think it totally worth it :)

Comment: can you explain some more details with sample, In case C component is globally shared so how we can use with B component and same time A component also.

Comment: @MiguelSsSRrR,  in my use case, I need to use a common singleton service on two different independent entry points  (say A and B module). Can you help me to understand how to call the common singleton service in two independent modules.

Comment: @dhana @sarangan I think you both have the same use case, and it is an extension of what I have explained above
- You need to create a separated entry point just for the shared logic (doesn't matter if it is a service, component or just a function), and import it on the consumers.

- Let's assume you create a `my-lib/common/shared` entry point with the logic you want to share.
- On consumer A or B you will need to `import {FantasticLogic} from 'my-lib/common/shared'`

Comment: @MiguelSsSRrR thanks a lot. It is working as expected